# Assign some tasks

Tags: list, tasks, app, task-list, contacts

I created the app Contacts and filled it with my employees.
Later, I created Tasks and wanted to assign some tasks to my employees. But when I type a name of my employee in the field `assign to`, nothing can be found:

[image: task]

Where do the contacts in the app Tasks come from?

Answer (score 0):

By default "Assigned to" is a SharePoint User field.

People picker is a control which used to set data for this field.

So, it show users (groups) from different data sources:

- The User Information List of the Site Collection.
- The User Profile Service (specifically the Root Organization)
- The configured data source for user information (Active Directory, AD LDS, SQL aspnetdb,
  etc).

You can replace this field with your own (for example lookup field to Contacts list).